# Only require a module if it is installed

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to tell if a module/package is available to use?

Something like this:

```
var moduleexists = require "moduleexists"

if (moduleexists("strangemodule")) {
  var strangemodule = require("strangemodule");

  strangeModule.doCoolStuff();
} else {
  // Do something without strangemodule
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `try..catch` to load the module in

```
try {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  var m = require('idontexist');                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
} catch(e) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 var m = {
    'doCoolStuff': function() { 
      .. 
    }
 };                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
} 

if (m.hasOwnProperty('doCoolStuff') && typeof m.doCoolStuff === 'function') {
   m.doCoolStuff();
}
```